# Separating data based on a row

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Sorry if the title is vague I didn't know how to describe this situation. I'm importing an excel file into a sql database which has worked. I have to take the information out of the database in separate chunks for each client number.
The excel file and database are formatted like this:

[image]

I was wondering if there was a way for me to separate the clients based on that one row they're referenced in.

Comment: That looks like date format more than a number.

Comment: The dates are the "data". The place where it says client number is a placeholder for the numbers. I didn't make it clear in the post that it was a mockup, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to adapt this code:

```

```
var rows = "a,1,2,3,4,b,5,6,7,8".Split(',');

var groupedByAlpha = rows
    .Aggregate(new List<ValueTuple<string, List<string>>>(), (acc, item) =>
    {
        if (Char.IsLetter(item[0]))
            acc.Add((item, new List<string>()));
        else
            acc.Last().Item2.Add(item);
        return acc;
    });
```

```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understand your question correctly you're just looking to SELECT a particular row. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/selecting-rows.html) is a quick guide on how you could go about doing this, you will send the same query regardless of whether you're doing it within SQL or in a C# environment.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I want to select the data after every client number and attach it to that client number when I export it. I didn't figure out a way to do it with a select statement but I might be overlooking something. The data changes monthly so i cant target the data itself with the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title and description, I'm assuming that both data and client numbers are in the same column. A better resolution to this from architecture standpoint would be to improve your schema and have a separate column for client numbers. The rules of schema design always require you to have the same kind of data in a column.

Applying these principles at this time would be advantageous as you are at the stage of creating tables and importing data. At later stages rectifying such a situation could be a disaster.